# speedata Publisher - how to insert a full size image

Tags: speedatapublisher

I use the speedata Publisher (the LuaTeX based database publishing software) and I'd like to insert a pdf file that covers the whole page. I have found the Image tag, but this gives me a margin at the top and the left and a blank page.

This is what I have now:

```
<Layout xmlns="urn:speedata.de:2009/publisher/en">

  <Record element="data">
    <PlaceObject>
      <Image width="210mm" file="mypdf.pdf"/>
    </PlaceObject>
  </Record>

</Layout>
```

(I cannot create a new tag speedatapublisher and there is none yet here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should specify the position of the image in absolute terms (0mm):

```
<Layout xmlns="urn:speedata.de:2009/publisher/en">

  <Record element="data">
    <PlaceObject column="0mm" row="0mm">
      <Image width="210mm" file="mypdf.pdf"/>
    </PlaceObject>
  </Record>

</Layout>
```

Hope this helps!